# i have the below method that compiles ok in the editor (blueJ) but when i try to test it i get an error message

Tags: java

below is the method. although it compiles ok in the editor when i try to test i get an error saying that it cannot find the method printReserve();

```
 /**
   * Public method that returns the reverse name
   */
   public void printReverse()
 {
  String a = new StringBuilder(this.getName()).reverse().toString();

  System.out.println(a);
 }
```

Comment: Lets see what is in the `main()` java method or wherever you are calling `printReserve()` method.

Comment: The nearest answer I can think off is, your method `printReverse()` is not a static method. Thus it cannot be called from a static method.

Comment: Your method is not called `printReserve`, it's called `printReverse`.